# Scritp VBA Identificar Entrada de Dados

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Boa tarde,

Possuo o código abaixo em VBA que me retorna as portas USB em uso. No entanto preciso saber qual delas que esta me enviando os dados do leitor de código de barra, pois utilizarei 8 leitores num único computador. Assim sendo preciso definir de qual leitor o script esta recebendo as informações.

```
Dim strComputer     As String
Dim strDeviceName   As String
Dim objWMIService   As Object
Dim colControllers  As Object
Dim objController   As Object
Dim colUSBDevices   As Object
Dim objUSBDevice    As Object

If TextBox2.Value = "" Then
    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colControllers = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_USBControllerDevice")

    For Each objController In colControllers
       strDeviceName = Replace(objController.Dependent, Chr(34), "")
       strDeviceName = Right(strDeviceName, Len(strDeviceName) - WorksheetFunction.Find("=", strDeviceName))
       Set colUSBDevices = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_PnPEntity Where DeviceID = '" & strDeviceName & "'")
        For Each objUSBDevice In colUSBDevices
            If objUSBDevice.DeviceID = "HID\VID_0C2E&PID_0B41&MI_00\7&33B8233E&0&0000" Then
end if
```